# What is the probability that both of the scores is a $3$?

Tags: probability, solution-verification

#### Question

> Someone rolls two identical fair 6-sided dice but does not know the result. Someone was told that one of the numbers on the die was a $3$. Given this information, what is the probability that both of the numbers on Someone's die was a $3$?

#### Answer

> $$ \frac{1}{11} $$

---

Given that the first number was a $3$, isn't the probability of the $2$<sup>nd</sup> die being $3$ equal to $\frac{1}{6}$? How is $\frac{1}{11}$ obtained?

Comment: Each pair is equally likely.  The pairs for which (at least) one is $3$ are $(1,3),(2,3),(3,3), (4,3),(5,3), (6,3), (3,1),(3,2),(3,4), (3,5), (3,6)$.  There are $11$ of these, and only one is $(3,3)$.

Comment: The problem and it's a standard one, with your argument is that no particular die was specified.  Had the observer told you "this particular die came up $3$", then you'd be correct.  The probability that the other die is $3$ would be $\frac 16$.  But that's not what we were told.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Given that the first number was a $3$, isn't the probability of the $2$<sup>nd</sup> die being $3$ equal to $\frac{1}{6}$?

No.

Using a Probability Diagram, draw all of the possible results:

|  | $1$ | $2$ | $3$ | $4$ | $5$ | $6$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $1$ | 1,1 | 2,1 | 3,1 | 4,1 | 5,1 | 6,1 |
| $2$ | 1,2 | 2,2 | 3,2 | 4,2 | 5,2 | 6,2 |
| $3$ | 1,3 | 2,3 | 3,3 | 4,3 | 5,3 | 6,3 |
| $4$ | 1,4 | 2,4 | 3,4 | 4,4 | 5,4 | 6,4 |
| $5$ | 1,5 | 2,5 | 3,5 | 4,5 | 5,5 | 6,5 |
| $6$ | 1,6 | 2,6 | 3,6 | 4,6 | 5,6 | 6,6 |

Now highlight all of the results with at least **one** $3$:

|  | $1$ | $2$ | $3$ | $4$ | $5$ | $6$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $1$ | 1,1 | 2,1 | **3,1** | 4,1 | 5,1 | 6,1 |
| $2$ | 1,2 | 2,2 | **3,2** | 4,2 | 5,2 | 6,2 |
| $3$ | **1,3** | **2,3** | **3,3** | **4,3** | **5,3** | **6,3** |
| $4$ | 1,4 | 2,4 | **3,4** | 4,4 | 5,4 | 6,4 |
| $5$ | 1,5 | 2,5 | **3,5** | 4,5 | 5,5 | 6,5 |
| $6$ | 1,6 | 2,6 | **3,6** | 4,6 | 5,6 | 6,6 |

If you count them, there are $11$ possible results with a $3$, and there is only **one** result which has two $3$s (3,3).

\begin{align}
\therefore P(\text{both of the numbers on the die was a 3}) &= \frac{n(\text{number of results with two 3s})}{n(\text{number of results with a 3})} \\
&= \frac{1}{11}
\end{align}